# postgres server works on LAN but not WAN (connection refused)

Tags: postgresql, local-area-network, wide-area-network, psql

I'm trying to set up a postgres server, but I cannot access it through the Internet.  It works fine on my LAN.  Server is just a desktop computer using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

**disclaimer**: I am not planning to use this configuration permanently.  Ultimately I will connect through an SSH tunnel and some of what I'm doing could be unsecure, but right now I just want to figure out why it's not working.

In my postgresql.conf file, I set `listen_addresses = '*'`.  To test that it wasn't something with my `pg_hba.conf`, I commented everything and just used

`host all all all trust`

There doesn't seem to be anything happening with the firewall - to make sure I installed gufw and allowed all incoming and outgoing traffic on both the server and client.

When I try to connect through my domain name, which points to the server's outside IP address, I get this message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "<hostname>" (<IP address>) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The result of `netstat -an | grep 5432` seems to indicate that postgres is indeed listening for connections on all addresses:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9771     /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Answer (score 0):

a line in pg_hba.conf, for e. g.:

`host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0               md5`

Comment: Isn't that more restrictive than what I had put in my pg_hba?  I thought what I had caused it to trust every connection.

Comment: Reading the doc would help you understand things correctly — there's no "all" for IP addresses. But `0.0.0.0/0` notation means any IP-addr. `trust` for every IP-addr is too insecure, that's why I put "md5" there, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't fix the problem, I still can't connect.

Comment: @buck, firewall? :)